# SQLSTATE HY024 with error message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid argument value

Tags: azure-sql-database, odbc, odbc-sql-server-driver

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL via a C++ program. However it is getting failed and I found the error with `SQLGetDiagRec` and `SQLGetDiagField`. The SQLSTATE is `HY024` with error message `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid argument value`

Below is the driver connection string I am using

```
    const char* cConnectString = "Driver=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server;Server=tcp:tmusqldev.database.windows.net,1433;Uid=tmu-admin;Pwd={PASSWORD};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;";  

   SQLDriverConnect( // SQL_NULL_HDBC  
                    hdbc,
                    nullptr,
                    (SQLWCHAR*)cConnectString,
                    strlen(cConnectString),
                    OutConnStr,
                    255,
                    &OutConnStrLen,
                    SQL_DRIVER_PROMPT);
```

When I test the connection from `ODBC Data Source Administrator`  its getting passed. I have attached screen shot for same.[image: ODBC Data Source Administrator]

Can someone suggest what might be wrong here ? I have tried by adding and removing multiple params but it has same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like the following:

```
// Connect to the driver.  Use the connection string if supplied
// on the input, otherwise let the driver manager prompt for input.

TRYODBC(hDbc,
    SQL_HANDLE_DBC,
    SQLDriverConnect(hDbc,
                     GetDesktopWindow(),
                     pwszConnStr,
                     SQL_NTS,
                     NULL,
                     0,
                     NULL,
                     SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE));
```

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/blob/master/VC2015Samples/ODBC%20database%20sample%20(windows)/C%2B%2B/odbcsql.cpp) you will find a full C++ ODBC Sample to connect to Azure SQL.